# Laravel Eloquent and SUM() - Do not consider the decimal

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I run in a strange issue, I need to sum a column using eloquent but every function I use eloquent do not consider the decimal.

First of all I have the column set ad `DECIMAL(8,2)` and in my DB the data is stored in the correct way.

[image]

If I just use a simple query:

```
select sum(total_after_tax) from invoice_details where invoice_id = 1
```

I get the result: `312.93`

Now if I use eloquent:

```
$invoice = Invoice::with(['details'])->get();
dd($invoice->first()->details->sum('total_after_tax'));
```

I get: `312`.

How is this possibile? How can I get the correct value form DB?

Comment: What Eloquent version are are you using? What about php? Using php 5.6.30 and illuminate/database v5.4.19 I get float(312.93)

Comment: I'm using php 7.0.13. Seems that the problem is that when I use `sum` on a collection it automatically round the value. How can I check eloquent version?

Comment: If you use composer then the version is defined in composer.json and composer.lock. Do you use Laravel or just Eloquent?

Comment: I use laravel so there is no eloquent in composer file